# Container auto-size to fixed-size elements only

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, win-universal-app, uwp-xaml

I have a RelativePanel with a fixed size element (in this case a TextBlock). This RelativePanel also has two Image elements with no Height/Width explicitly set, but set to stretch. What I want is that the RelativePanel (or some other container) adjusts its size to accommodate the TextBlock and then have the Images scale to fill the space that's left for them.

The RelativePanel is arranged horizontally, going like (generic example):

```
<RelativePanel Height="80">
    <Image Source="..."/>
    <TextBlock Text="..."/>
    <Image Source="..."/>
</RelativePanel>
```

What would be a good way to accomplish this?

Edit: [Image of what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EwoQN.jpg)

Comment: If container auto-size to a inside element that has fixed side, how did it have left space for image to fill? Did you mean you want the image as the background of the text? If that, why you need two images? To upload a picture to show what you actually want will be much better.

Comment: @sunteen "If container auto-size to a inside element that has fixed side, how did it have left space for image to fill?" - Because it auto-sizes only its height, and the image goes to the left of the fixed size element, thus it is not affected.
"Did you mean you want the image as the background of the text?' - No.
I will update with a representation of what I mean

Answer (score 0):

Images control has Stretch="UniformToFill" property that will display image in available space.

Can you try with this

```
<RelativePanel x:Name="mainPanel" Height="80">
    <Image x:Name="Img1" Source="..." Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="TxtBlock1" Text="..."/ RelativePanel.AlignLeftWith="Img1" Width=150>
    <Image x:Name="Img2" Source="..." Stretch="UniformToFill" RelativePanel.AlignLeftWith="TxtBlock1"/></RelativePanel>
```

Comment: I'll be testing it out, but isn't "UniformToFill" meant to scale the image's dimensions independently to the maximum allowed by the UI, differing from the default "Uniform" only because the latter keeps the image's aspect ratio? If so, it wouldn't help since "Uniform" is already there and not working like I wanted

Comment: Just tested it, as I expected it didn't work, but thanks for the help!